# wpf - Binding issue ActualWidth

Tags: wpf, binding, actualwidth

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="grid_StatusBar">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=wrapPanel, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ProgressBar Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" Name="wrapPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Label Content="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="label_Dataset" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <Label Content="/20" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="label_TotalDatasets" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <Label Content="ID:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="label_IDText" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Label Content="no id" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="labelID" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </WrapPanel>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Name="button_Help" Height="30" Width="30" Content="?" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="button_Help_Click" >
</Grid>
```

What i am trying to show the progressbar as wide as possible while changing the visibility of some of the labels and setting different texts (and therefore different lengths/widths.

I have then different functions:

- At program start the "no id" text of the `labelID` Label is replaced with an internal value. *The width is updated*: **OK**
- With the code running I change the visibility of the first two labels, and the `ColumnDefinition.Width` is not updated and only the first two labels are shown (because there is not place enough for all the 4 of them to fit in the wrapPanel ActualWidth: **ERROR!**
- If I change the `Visibility` property from the first two Labels from `Collapsed` to `Visible`, from start the visibility of all the Labels are `Visible`, and all the Labels are shown: **OK**
- From the previous state I change visibility of the first two Labels to `Collapsed`, the `ColumnDefinition.Width` is updated and the `ProgressBar` is as wide as possible and all the text is shown: **OK**

Could anyone please help me? I do not understand why the width is not updated...

**NOTE:** The visibility is changed using two buttons in the window running the following code:

```
label_Dataset.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
label_TotalDatasets.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

**EDIT:** My target is to show the Visible Labels using the minimum space (in one line) in order to have the ProgressBar using the maximum width possible.

Comment: Set the column width to `Auto` <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />  and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the width of a parent element based on the width of a child.  In your case, the column is the parent of the `WrapPanel`, so the `ActualWidth` of the `WrapPanel` is not available until after the grid/column has already been sized.

Even if you wrote code to try and circumvent this, you would still run into an issue, as the measure/layout sequence would become re-entrant. Whenever the size of the column changed, it would re-layout all the child controls, one of which is the `WrapPanel`.  This would cause the `ActualWidth` of the `WrapPanel` to be changed -- effectively causing an infinite loop.  To prevent this stack overflow scenario, the framework immediately detects any re-entrancy in the layout/measure cycle and throws an exception.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. Why do would you want the Labels in a `WrapPanel`? Surely you would always want the 4 labels to be on the same line, or at least on two lines.

If this is the case, I would set the width of the second Column to "Auto" and put the labels in another container, i.e. one of the following:

- If you want all the labels to wrap, as in a `WrapPanel` being forced to its minimum width, use:

  ```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
      ... your labels here ...
  </StackPanel>
  ```
- If you want all the labels to stay on the same line, use:

  ```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
      ... your labels here ...
  </StackPanel>
  ```
- If you want two lines use:

  ```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          ... 1st 2 labels here  ...
      </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          ... 2nd 2 labels here  ...
      </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
  ```

Comment: Hi @Peter and thanks! It worked changing it to a StackPanel.. I just wanted to show the Visible Labels using the minimum space (in one line) in order to have the ProgressBar using the maximum width possible.

I just changed `WrapPanel` to `StackPanel` and the `ColumnDefinition` Width to `Auto` and it is shown just like I want it to...

Thanks again!

Comment: "It is not possible to change the width of a parent element based on the width of a child": I think the `Canvas` panel is one exception to this general rule, but only because it doesn't size itself based on its children.